# S3 Protocol (Aws, minio etc...) List subset ordered by creation date DESC

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, key, protocols, minio

Is there a way to query a s3 “folder” without retrieving every single entity?
I need to query an s3 folder (where I have no control over) and it has 60k elements, it’s taking like 5 minutes to list everything. I would need to retrieve only the last 10 elements ordered by creation date desc.

Is there a way to do this with the s3 protocol?

By the way, the server could also be using something other than aws as the s3 provider, and I don't have access to the server.

Thanks a lot!

I tried using the minio client to verify from the available methods. I didn't find anyhthing unfortunately.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this with the s3 protocol?" No.  If it's S3 proper, you can setup an S3 Inventory report and load that as a single file.